# iOS link to app store before submitting an app

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, google-play

I'm building an "About" controller for my iPhone app. I've see other apps successfully include a "rate in market" link to within their "About" controllers.

Is it possible for me to predict what my link would be, so I can hard-code it in the first release of the app, rather than uploading/figuring out the link/releasing the update?

For example an **android app** market link may look like :

```
https://market.android.com/details?id=[package name]
```

for Android, there's an action view with a market URL that may be opened to link right to the app.

**Is there a corresponding action within iOS? I want the customer to be able to navigate to the app's page on the app store  from my "About" controller.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the [iTunes link maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/).  It looks like the generic form is:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/[APPNAME]/id[APP_ID]
```

Some examples:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myapp/id427813331?mt=8&uo=4
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hot-radar/id308361196?mt=8&uo=4
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightshow-!/id380886382?mt=8&uo=4
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/disney-world-park-maps-by/id392534629?mt=8&uo=4
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/universal-park-maps-orlando/id392535133?mt=8&uo=4
```

I think `APP_ID` refers to the iTunes Connect App ID for your product.  So if you have that, and the name, your good to go!

Answer (score 3):

Also when you create an app in iTunes Connect you have link View this app in app store there which you can use directly even if it is not published or sent to apple, so as soon as you create it with basic info you will have link there which you can copy.

Answer (score 2):

By now Apple has introduced short-links via the `appstore.com` domain:

> **Q: How can I create easy-to-read short links to the App Store for my apps and company?**
>
> iOS: `http://appstore.com/<appname>` for example, `http://appstore.com/keynote`

See [Technical Q&A QA1633](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1633/_index.html) for the full description of the possibilities.